# Unable to get chartjs to draw a chart with dynamic data (variable not hardcoded)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to use chart.js to draw a chart. My use case is very simple, I'm getting data from my database that needs to be plotted on a line chart. I'm able to get the chart to work when using hardcoded data (i.e)

```
data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Occupancy",
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [1,2,3],
            }]
        },
```

When trying to replace data: [1,2,3] with a variable array, I get an error in the console:

```
       var occ_labels = $('.chart_data_class')[0].dataset['occLbl'];
    //var occ_labels =["1","2","3"];
    console.log(occ_labels);
    var occ_twentyfive = $('.chart_data_class')[0].dataset['occ-25'];
    var ctx_occ = document.getElementById('occ-chart').getContext('2d');
    console.log(ctx_occ);
    var chart = new Chart(ctx_occ, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Occupancy",
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: occ_twentyfive,
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
          legend: false,
        }
    });

    var ctx_adr = document.getElementById('adr-chart').getContext('2d');
```

Then the following error occurs:

```
jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:3828 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
at e (Chart.min.js:12)
at a.buildOrUpdateElements (Chart.min.js:12)
at t.Controller.<anonymous> (Chart.min.js:11)
at Object.o.each (Chart.min.js:12)
at t.Controller.update (Chart.min.js:11)
at t.Controller.initialize (Chart.min.js:11)
at new t.Controller (Chart.min.js:11)
at new t (Chart.min.js:12)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (interest.self-8876b9dfa2300b4adb2cc9db31f03dcc885a83d23bfc2247d8c08fa65a545fe9.js?body=1:16)
```

Nothing else changed besides that variable. The variable is valid and has been printed in the console. I have also tried setting the variable as follows:

```
var occ_twentyfive = [1,2,3];
```

and that doesn't work either. Thoughts? I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out what's the issue and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you show how you use the variable in your code? I do not see `occ_twentyfive` being used anywhere.

Comment: It replaces data [1,2,3] so instead of the code above saying data [1,2,3], it would say occ_twentyfive updated above.

Comment: Confirm that occ_twentyfive is of type array

Comment: it is, for simplicity and testing sake, I have it set to be [1,2,3] which is the same. Surprisingly enough, I just went back to the page and it seems to be working now even though I had started and restarted the server multiple times before. Perhaps something was caching somewhere and waiting a few days to retry fixed it somehow. not sure what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, I just went back to the page and it seems to be working now even though I had started and restarted the server multiple times before. Perhaps something was caching somewhere and waiting a few days to retry fixed it somehow. not sure what happened...